# Issue: Deploying a Model using Azure Machine Learning Service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, web-services, web-deployment

I created a classifier model using Azure Machine Learning service, after successfully registering a model i built the correct environment for container instance providing scoring  file, environment file and configuration file  Unfortunately  when I am deploying my solution it's giving me the error, however here is my deployment service logs to get more details:

**service Logs**

```
2020-02-07T06:21:10,612616835+00:00 - rsyslog/run 
2020-02-07T06:21:10,616528746+00:00 - iot-server/run 
2020-02-07T06:21:10,617958751+00:00 - gunicorn/run 
2020-02-07T06:21:10,627065178+00:00 - nginx/run 
EdgeHubConnectionString and IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME are not set. Exiting...
2020-02-07T06:21:11,108893523+00:00 - iot-server/finish 1 0
2020-02-07T06:21:11,116794547+00:00 - Exit code 1 is normal. Not restarting iot-server.
Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:31311 (12)
Using worker: sync
worker timeout is set to 300
Booting worker with pid: 45
Initializing logger
Starting up app insights client
Starting up request id generator
Starting up app insight hooks
Invoking user's init function
2020-02-07 06:21:15,494 | azureml.core.run | DEBUG | Could not load run context RunEnvironmentException:
    Message: Could not load a submitted run, if outside of an execution context, use experiment.start_logging to initialize an azureml.core.Run.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Could not load a submitted run, if outside of an execution context, use experiment.start_logging to initialize an azureml.core.Run."
    }
}, switching offline: False
2020-02-07 06:21:15,495 | azureml.core.run | DEBUG | Could not load the run context and allow_offline set to False
2020-02-07 06:21:15,495 | azureml.core.model | DEBUG | Checking root for demo_Model.pkl because candidate dir azureml-models had 1 nodes: azureml-models/demomodel/8/demo_Model.pkl
User's init function failed
Encountered Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/azureml-server/aml_blueprint.py", line 163, in register
    main.init()
  File "/var/azureml-app/main.py", line 88, in init
    driver_module.init()
  File "score.py", line 13, in init
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('demo_Model.pkl')
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py", line 697, in get_model_path
    return Model._get_model_path_local(model_name, version)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py", line 718, in _get_model_path_local
    return Model._get_model_path_local_from_root(model_name)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py", line 761, in _get_model_path_local_from_root
    "set logging level to DEBUG.".format(candidate_model_path))
azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.ModelNotFoundException: ModelNotFoundException:
    Message: Model not found in cache or in root at ./demo_Model.pkl. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Model not found in cache or in root at ./demo_Model.pkl. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG."
    }
}

/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: FutureWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=FutureWarning)
Worker exiting (pid: 45)
Shutting down: Master
Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-02-07T06:21:15,663509630+00:00 - gunicorn/finish 3 0
2020-02-07T06:21:15,664398433+00:00 - Exit code 3 is not normal. Killing image.
```

**Error**
    Running..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
TimedOut

ERROR - Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
Error:
{
  "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice."
}

ERROR - Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
Error:
{
  "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice."
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/webservice.py in wait_for_deployment(self, show_output)
    530                                           'Error:\n'
--> 531                                           '{}'.format(self.state, logs_response, error_response), logger=module_logger)
    532             print('{} service creation operation finished, operation "{}"'.format(self._webservice_type,

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
Error:
{
  "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice."
}
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy\nMore information can be found using '.get_logs()'\nError:\n{\n  \"code\": \"DeploymentTimedOut\",\n  \"statusCode\": 504,\n  \"message\": \"The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice.\"\n}"
    }
}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/webservice.py in wait_for_deployment(self, show_output)
    538                                           'Current state is {}'.format(self.state), logger=module_logger)
    539             else:
--> 540                 raise WebserviceException(e.message, logger=module_logger)
    541 
    542     def _wait_for_operation_to_complete(self, show_output):

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
Error:
{
  "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice."
}
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy\nMore information can be found using '.get_logs()'\nError:\n{\n  \"code\": \"DeploymentTimedOut\",\n  \"statusCode\": 504,\n  \"message\": \"The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. From SDK you can run print(service.state) to know the current state of the webservice.\"\n}"
    }
}
```

That's how my webservice code look like:

```
%%time
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.environment import Environment

myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name="myenv", file_path="myenv.yml")
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py", environment=myenv)

service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                       name='myimage',
                       models=[model], 
                       inference_config=inference_config,
                       deployment_config=aciconfig)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

can anyone tell me what it actually means? How can i solve this?

Thanks

Ahmad

Comment: please show relevant code how you create the webservice

Comment: Thank you silent for your response, can you please check my post with webservice code??

Comment: Hi silent,
Did you check the my post?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the version of scikit-learn solved it in my environment.

Specify the version into `myenv.yml` as follows.
(In my environment, 0.20.3 is initially installed, and solved by updating to 0.22.1)

```
name: project_environment
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.
  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.
- python=3.6.2

- pip:
  - azureml-defaults
- scikit-learn=0.22.1
channels:
- conda-forge
```